# Image size control in Rmarkdown pdf generation with latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using Rmarkdownv2 to generate a pdf file with some local images. But it seems that the image was converted to a larger size with lower resolution in the rendered pdf, compared to the html. The code I'm currently using for the image is something like:
`![alt text](figures/fig1.png)`

Is there any way to control the image size in the pdf? I also tried

`pdf_document:
    fig_height: 1
    fig_width: 2`

But that didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [development version of **knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) (>= v1.11.22) and the `include_graphics()` function, e.g.

````
```{r out.width='70%'}
knitr::include_graphics('figures/fig1.png')
```
````

If you want a figure caption, just use the chunk option `fig.cap = 'A figure caption.'`