# Iteratively producing latex tables in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm working on iteratively producing LaTeX tables using knitr. All is well except I'm left with extra markup before each table. Here's a simple example, though this would ideally work as a template for more complex problems, ie different-size tables, varying data sets etc.

What can I do to get rid of the extra text before each table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace, relsize}
\usepackage[margin=.5in, landscape]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = FALSE, error = FALSE)
library("ggplot2")
library("knitr")
library("Hmisc")

mytable_function = function(mydata){
  foo = as.matrix(head(mydata))
  colnames(foo) = names(mydata)
  rownames(foo) = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth")
  return(foo)
}

template <- "<<thisthing-{{i}}>>=
mytable = mytable_function(iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i],])
latex(mytable, file = '',
        title = '',
        where = '!h',
        caption = 'This is a table',
        col.just = rep('r', ncol(mytable)))
@"

 for(i in 1:3){
    cat(knit(text = knit_expand(text = template, i = i, quiet = TRUE)))
 }

@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Fwiw here's a similar question I asked a while ago but because I'm producing tables here and not figures I think this is a slightly different solution.
[Print a list of dynamically-sized plots in knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701038/print-a-list-of-dynamically-sized-plots-in-knitr)

Comment: If you are going to be using these tables in another document, you might want to just save the text output of each and then use `\input` (I think that the right Latex command) to read them in your final document. One example is using `xtable`, create the `xtable` object, then in `print()` you can add a file argument to save the output.  I suspect that the `Hmisc` function has a similar argument.

Answer (score 1):

The provided code does not match the output you presented. Actually, it produces no output whatsoever.

## Step 0: Reproduce output from the question

- `include=FALSE` on the only chunk in the document is quite fatal … replace by `echo=FALSE`.
- The main chunk (`setup`) as well as the template chunk need `results="asis"`.
- `message=FALSE` should be a chunk option of `setup`. Setting it as default options within `setup` won't affect messages from the current chunk.

## Step 1: Immediate issue

This line

```
cat(knit(text = knit_expand(text = template, i = i, quiet = TRUE)))
```

shoud be

```
cat(knit(text = knit_expand(text = template, i = i), quiet = TRUE))
```

`quiet` is an argument of `knit`, not `knit_expand`.

## Step 2: A better solution

Although this works, it's an overly complicated overkill. The answer you linked to dynamically generated chunks because `fig.height` is not vectorized the way it would be required for that case. Here, we can just use a single chunk:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, echo = FALSE, results='asis', message = FALSE>>=

mytable_function = function(mydata){
  foo = as.matrix(head(mydata))
  colnames(foo) = names(mydata)
  rownames(foo) = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth")
  return(foo)
}

for(i in 1:3){
  mytable = mytable_function(iris[iris$Species == unique(iris$Species)[i],])
  Hmisc::latex(mytable, 
        file = '',
        title = '',
        where = '!h',
        caption = 'This is a table',
        col.just = rep('r', ncol(mytable)))
}

@
\end{document}
```