# Adding text to a grid.table plot

Tags: r

I have recently started using the `grid.table` function from the `gridExtra` package to turn tabular data into png image files for use on the web. I've been delighted with it so far as it produces very good-looking output by default, sort of like a `ggplot2` for tables. Like the person who [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432836/conditionally-formatting-tables-using-gridextra-in-r) this question I would love to see the ability to specify the justification for individual columns but that would be icing on what is an already more-ish cake.

My question is whether it is possible to add text around a `grid.table` so that I can give plotted tables a title and a footnote. It seems to me this should be feasible, but I don't know enough about grid graphics to be able to work out how to add grobs to the table grob. For example, this code:

```
require(gridExtra)

mydf <- data.frame(Item = c('Item 1','Item 2','Item 3'), 
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Value = c(10,15,20), check.names = FALSE)
grid.table(mydf,
           gpar.coretext=gpar(fontsize = 16),
           gpar.coltext = gpar(fontsize = 16),
           gpar.rowtext = gpar(fontsize = 16),
           gpar.corefill = gpar(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5, col = NA),
           h.even.alpha = 0.5,
           equal.width = FALSE,
           show.rownames = FALSE,
           show.vlines = TRUE,
           padding.h = unit(15, "mm"),
           padding.v = unit(8, "mm")
           )
```

generates this plot:

[image]

when I would really like to be able to do something like the following in code rather than by editing the image with another application:

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To place text close to the table you'll want to evaluate the table size first,

```
library(gridExtra)
d <- head(iris)
table <- tableGrob(d)

grid.newpage()
h <- grobHeight(table)
w <- grobWidth(table)
title <- textGrob("Title", y=unit(0.5,"npc") + 0.5*h, 
                  vjust=0, gp=gpar(fontsize=20))
footnote <- textGrob("footnote", 
                     x=unit(0.5,"npc") - 0.5*w,
                     y=unit(0.5,"npc") - 0.5*h, 
                  vjust=1, hjust=0,gp=gpar( fontface="italic"))
gt <- gTree(children=gList(table, title, footnote))
grid.draw(gt)
```

**Edit (17/07/2015)** With gridExtra >=2.0.0, this approach is no longer suitable. tableGrob now returns a gtable, which can be more easily customised.

```
library(gridExtra)
d <- head(iris)
table <- tableGrob(d)

library(grid)
library(gtable)

title <- textGrob("Title",gp=gpar(fontsize=50))
footnote <- textGrob("footnote", x=0, hjust=0,
                     gp=gpar( fontface="italic"))

padding <- unit(0.5,"line")
table <- gtable_add_rows(table, 
                         heights = grobHeight(title) + padding,
                         pos = 0)
table <- gtable_add_rows(table, 
                         heights = grobHeight(footnote)+ padding)
table <- gtable_add_grob(table, list(title, footnote),
                         t=c(1, nrow(table)), l=c(1,2), 
                         r=ncol(table))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(table)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem and I learned several things from that. I guess I can also use the table and text grobs in viewports and so on?

Comment: sure, you can give a vp to the gTree

Comment: it works, but the color of the table is gone after using this. I can only color to title.

Answer (score 5):

If you want *just* the title (no footnote), here is a simplified version of @baptiste's example:

```
title <- textGrob("Title", gp = gpar(fontsize = 50))
padding <- unit(0.5,"line")
table <- gtable_add_rows(
  table, heights = grobHeight(title) + padding, pos = 0
)
table <- gtable_add_grob(
  table, list(title),
  t = 1, l = 1, r = ncol(table)
)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(table)
```