# grid.arrange align all tables to the top in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How do I align all tables in `grid.arrange` to top? The tables seem to mid-align by default.

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3), y=c('a', 'b', 'c'))
df2 = data.frame(x=rep(1, 10), y=rep('a', 10))
grid.arrange(tableGrob(df1), tableGrob(df2),
             nrow=1, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g1 <- tableGrob(df1)    
g2 <- tableGrob(df2)

grid.draw(combine(g1, g2, along=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried to mix in textGrob but it doesn't work. Could you point me to the right direction?

title1 = textGrob('Title 1')

title2 = textGrob('Title 2')

grid.draw(title1, title2, combine(g1, g2, along=1))

Comment: Can I check if your intention were to add  a title on top of each tableGrob object? If so, [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640916/how-can-i-add-a-title-to-a-tablegrob-plot)

Comment: Also, you could check out [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html), which is quite helpful for some other layout.