# Title getting cut off using grid.arrange

Tags: r, gridextra, gtable

I built a function for quickly plotting a table with a lot of help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11775211/2146894) from @baptiste.

```
plotTable<-function(data, title=NULL, footnote=NULL, fontsize=9, plotIt=TRUE, show.rownames=TRUE){
  # Generic method to plot tabular data

  # Built the base table with/without row names
  if(show.rownames){
    table <- tableGrob(data, theme=ttheme_default(
      core=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=fontsize)),
      colhead=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=fontsize)),
      rowhead=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=fontsize))))
  } else{
    table <- tableGrob(data, theme=ttheme_default(
      core=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=fontsize)),
      colhead=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=fontsize)),
      rowhead=list(fg_params=list(fontsize=fontsize))), rows=NULL)
  }

  # Set the padding
  padding <- unit(0.5,"line")

  # Add the title if it's not NULL
  if(!is.null(title)){
    title.grob <- textGrob(title, gp=gpar(fontsize=fontsize+3))
    table <- gtable_add_rows(table, heights = grobHeight(title.grob) + padding, pos = 0)
    table <- gtable_add_grob(table, list(title.grob), t=1, l=1, r=ncol(table))
  }

  # Add the footnote if it's not NULL
  if(!is.null(footnote)){
    footnote.grob <- textGrob(footnote, x=0, hjust=0, gp=gpar(fontsize=fontsize, fontface="italic"))
    table <- gtable_add_rows(table, heights = grobHeight(footnote.grob)+ padding)
    table <- gtable_add_grob(table, list(footnote.grob), t=nrow(table), l=1, r=ncol(table))
  }

  # Either plot it or return the grob
  if(plotIt) grid.arrange(table) else return(table)
}
```

But sometimes my title is longer than the actual table and it's getting cut off.

```
libs <- c("data.table", "grid", "gridExtra", "gtable")
lapply(libs, library, character.only = TRUE)

mytable <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(3,2,1))
plotTable(mytable, title="Hello World")
```

[image: the table]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Two possibilities, (i) try to reduce the font size in `title.grob <- textGrob(title, gp=gpar(fontsize=fontsize+3))`, (ii) enter a new line after `Hello`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the table widths manually, but you'll need to decide which column(s) should be expanded and by how much. I guess a reasonable way to redistribute the widths is to add the same margin to each column, so that the total space gained accounts for the extra room needed for the title.

[image]

```
library(gridExtra)
d <- head(iris[,1:2])
table <- tableGrob(d, rows=NULL)

library(grid)
library(gtable)

title <- textGrob("my long title goes here",gp=gpar(fontsize=30))
padding <- unit(1,"line")
table <- gtable_add_rows(table, 
                         heights = grobHeight(title) + padding,
                         pos = 0)
table <- gtable_add_grob(table, title,
                         t=1, l=1, 
                         r=ncol(table))

# check whether the table width is smaller than the title width
missed <- convertWidth(sum(table$widths), "in", valueOnly = TRUE) -
  convertWidth(grobWidth(title), "in", valueOnly = TRUE)

if(missed < 0 ) # need to do something about it
  table$widths <- table$widths + unit(abs(missed)/ncol(table), "in")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(table)
```

Answer (score 4):

another option, if you don't want the cells to be resized, is to turn clipping off,

```
table$layout$clip <- "off"
```

[image]