# Adding a subtitle text to a grid.table plot

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

I have a question very similar to what discussed here:
[Adding text to a grid.table plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774703/adding-text-to-a-grid-table-plot)
my ultimate goal however is to have a title 60mm from the top of the table, and a subtitle 2mm below the title.
I came up with this code that is almost there but not there, meaning, the subtitle is 2mm from the top of the table, and 2mm below the title, as expected.

```
library(gridExtra)
  library(grid)
  library(gtable)
  d <- head(iris)
  table <- tableGrob(d)
  
  title <- textGrob("Title",gp=gpar(fontsize=50))
  subtitle <- textGrob("subtitle", x=0, hjust=0,
                       gp=gpar( fontface="italic"))
  
  padding <- unit(2,"mm")
  
  table <- gtable_add_rows(table, 
                           heights = grobHeight(subtitle)+ padding,
                           pos = 0)
  
  padding <- unit(60,"mm")
  table <- gtable_add_rows(table, 
                           heights = grobHeight(title) + padding,
                           pos = 0)
  
  table <- gtable_add_grob(table, list(title, subtitle),
                           t=c(1, 2), l=c(1,1), 
                           r=ncol(table))
  png('tmp.png', width = 480, height = 480, bg = "#FFECDB")
  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(table)
  dev.off()
```

I wonder if anybody has a suggestion on how to fix it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to grid tables, but it appears the order of your grobs matters, at least for padding. Is this the result you are expecting?

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

d <- head(iris)
table <- tableGrob(d)

title <- textGrob("Title", gp = gpar(fontsize=50))
subtitle <- textGrob("subtitle", x=0, hjust=0, gp=gpar( fontface="italic"))

table <- gtable_add_rows(table, heights = grobHeight(subtitle) + unit(58,"mm"), pos = 0)
table <- gtable_add_rows(table, heights = grobHeight(title) - unit(60,"mm"), pos = 0)
table <- gtable_add_grob(table, list(title, subtitle), t=c(1,2), l=c(1,1), r=ncol(table))

png('tmp.png', width = 480, height = 480, bg = "#FFECDB")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(table)

dev.off()
```

[image: title subtitle 60]

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Good luck!