# How to append input file name to corresponding list output index in R

Tags: r, list, csv

How do I append the name of corresponding file name to the list output of my code. The goal is to be able to trace the outputs in the list to the input csv files. Currently, the list output returns a list index `[[1]]`,`[[2]]`,`...`,`[[5]]` (see the snapshot below). I want the corresponding file name included, something like this `CA_three` , `FL_three`,`....`, `NY_two`

[image]

@ Akrun, I want each page to have a corresponding file name

[image]

Below there are two codes

- Code 1 : code that loops through 5 csv files and returns a list of outputs `[[]]` (I need help here)
- Code 2: code to generate 5 csv files used in `Code 1`

```
# Code 1
library(multcompView) # for tukeyHD

# list of 20 csv files in a folder

files <- list.files("C:\\mypath\\", pattern="*.csv", full.names = T)

out <- lapply(1:length(files), function(x) {  # use lapply to loop over all files
  
  this_data <- read.csv(files[x], header = TRUE)
  aov_mod <- aov(revenue ~ dept, data = this_data)
  tuk<-TukeyHSD(x= aov_mod)
  tuk
  

})

out
```

```
# Code 2
# In order to generate 5 csv files, copy and paste the code below and save in a new folder
# 

state <-c("NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY")

dept <- c("energy","energy","energy","energy","works",'works','works','works','fin','fin','fin','fin','parks','parks','parks','parks','trans','trans','trans','trans')
year <- c("two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two","two")
revenue <-c(1212.9,1253,1244.4,5123.5,1312,3134,515.8,2449.9,3221.6,3132.5,2235.09,2239.01,3235.01,5223.01,4235.6,2204.5,2315.5,6114,4512,3514.2)
NY_two <-data.frame(state,dept,year,revenue)
# dataset 2
state <-c("NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY","NY")

dept <- c("energy","energy","energy","energy","works",'works','works','works','fin','fin','fin','fin','parks','parks','parks','parks','trans','trans','trans','trans')
year <- rep("five",20)
revenue <-c(1212.9,1253,1244.4,5123.5,1312,3134,515.8,2449.9,3221.6,3132.5,2235.09,2239.01,3235.01,5223.01,4235.6,2204.5,2315.5,6114,4512,3514.2)
NY_five <-data.frame(state,dept,year,revenue)



state <- rep("FL",20)
dept <- c("energy","energy","energy","energy","works",'works','works','works','fin','fin','fin','fin','parks','parks','parks','parks','trans','trans','trans','trans')
year <- rep("three",20)
revenue <-c(112.9,123,124,523.5,112,334,55,449,221.6,332,235,239,235,223,235.6,204,315.5,614,512,514.2)
FL_three <- data.frame(state,dept,year,revenue)



state <- rep("CA",20)
dept <- c("energy","energy","energy","energy","works",'works','works','works','fin','fin','fin','fin','parks','parks','parks','parks','trans','trans','trans','trans')
year <- rep("three",20)
revenue <-c(1102.9,1023,1024,5203.5,1012,3034,505,4049,2021.6,3032,2035,2039,2035,2023,2035.6,2004,3015.5,6014,5012,5014.2)
CA_three <- data.frame(state,dept,year,revenue)


state <- rep("KY",20)
dept <- c("energy","energy","energy","energy","works",'works','works','works','fin','fin','fin','fin','parks','parks','parks','parks','trans','trans','trans','trans')
year <- rep("one",20)
revenue <-c(1102.9,1023,1024,5203.5,1012,3034,505,4049,2021.6,3032,2035,2039,2035,2023,2035.6,2004,3015.5,6014,5012,5014.2)
KY_one <- data.frame(state,dept,year,revenue)



setwd("C:\\define your path\\")

# writing out the file to a newly created folder
write.csv(NY_two,"NY_two.csv",row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(CA_three,"CA_three.csv",row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(FL_three,"FL_three.csv",row.names = F)
write.csv(NY_five,"NY_five.csv",row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(KY_one,"KY_one.csv",row.names = F)
```

Please share your code, thanx in advance!

Comment: You may need to create a named `list`

Comment: @akrun, Please can you share you code (add comments too). thanks

Comment: I believe you are reading from the `files` i.e. `files <- list.files("C:\\mypath\\", pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)`  Are those file names you wanted i.e. `filenms <- sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(files))` and then when you get the output set the names to `names(out) <- filenms`

Comment: Yes, all the files

Comment: share your full code pls

Comment: Once you have named it, then it is easier i.e. `purrr::iwalk(out, ~ write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun, post your code in answer section (instead of the comment section), this will help me understand your logic. Also, so I can vote your response as answered. Really appreciate your effort

Comment: Thanks, I posted as a solution.  I didn't answer earlier as I was not sure whether that is what you wanted

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I updated the solution as your TukeyHSD is a list and it may be better to make it a tibble with `tidy` from `broom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'out' `list` doesn't have any names because it was not named.  If the names should come from the `files` part, we may name the output ('out') with the substring of file names

```
# returns all the file paths for csv
files <- list.files("C:\\mypath\\", pattern="\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE) 
# get the substring of file names without the .csv part
filenms <- sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(files))
```

Now, we use the same code as in the OP's post or just loop over the files directly

```
out <- lapply(files, function(x) {  # use lapply to loop over all files
  
  this_data <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE)
  aov_mod <- aov(revenue ~ dept, data = this_data)
  tuk <- TukeyHSD(x= aov_mod)
  # output of TukeyHSD is a list which can be summarised into tibble
  # with tidy from broom
  broom::tidy(tuk)
  

})
# set the names with filenms
names(out) <- filenms
```

If we want to write the output use `imap/iwalk` from `purrr` which is concise as `.y` returns the names and `.x` returns the value of the `list`

```
purrr::iwalk(out, ~ write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE))
```

---

If we want `pdf` file, an option is to use [`tableGrob`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774703/adding-text-to-a-grid-table-plot)

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(gtable)
# reproducible exmaple
out <- list(iris = head(iris), mtcars = head(mtcars))
pdf(file.path(getwd(), "Downloads/filepdfMar9.pdf"))
iwalk(out,  ~ {
     
     title <- textGrob(.y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 50))
     padding <- unit(0.5,"line")
     x1 <- gtable_add_rows(
     tableGrob(.x), heights = grobHeight(title) + padding, pos = 0
       )
    x1 <- gtable_add_grob(
      x1, list(title),
        t = 1, l = 1, r = ncol(x1)
    )
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(x1)
})
dev.off()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Everything works up until the purr::walk, I got this error `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("TukeyHSD", "multicomp")’ to a data.frame`

Comment: @RickyTricky can you try the `out` updated.  may be you used earlier version

Comment: works well thanks alot. One last thing, instead of exporting the final output as csv (`purrr::iwalk`) can you export them as 1 pdf file with multiple pages?

Comment: @RickyTricky then you may need to convert as image and use `pdf`

Comment: i hope I am not asking for too much, can you modify the code to convert as image and export as pdf. Thanks alot

Comment: @RickyTricky you may try `library(gridExtra);
pdf("yourfile.pdf", height=11, width=10);
iwalk(out, ~ grid.table(.x));
dev.off()`

Comment: where do I place the `pdf("your file.pdf")`....Please include al the suggested codes in the previous code you provided earlier. I will prefer it to be 1 large pdf file with multiple page instead of multiple pdf files. I really appreciate your assistance, I'm still pretty new to R

Comment: @RickyTricky yes, that is why you have to include the `pdf(...)` command before the loop in `iwalk`, which should generate multiple pages

Comment: @RickyTricky please check the update in my post

Comment: thanks alot. the output is not showing the corresponding file names ( I have added an example of the output in my original post). How can we include filenames each page.?

Comment: @RickyTricky you can modify the one I updated.  Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774703/adding-text-to-a-grid-table-plot) as well

Comment: How do i automate the `TableGrob` for all the tables?